# Error when passing data from view to controller using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I need to pass the id of the checked field and a string "checked" to the database through ajax.I am not at all familiar with ajax

```
      <h2 id="h2">To Do List</h2>
      <ul id="new">
       <?php if(!empty($details)){ foreach($details as $key => $del) {  ?>
   <li id="try-0"><input class= "box" type="checkbox"><input class="set field" name="list[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $del['value'];?>"></li>          
          <?php  } ?>

                <li id="try-0"><input class= "box" type="checkbox"><input class="set field" name="list[]" style="margin: 5px 0 5px 10px;width: 297px;height: 35px;" type="text" value=""></li>

     <?php } else{ ?>

        <li id="try-0"><input class= "box" type="checkbox"><input class="set field" name="list[]" type="text" value=""></li>
      <?php } ?>   

     </ul>
        <button class="btn btn-info" id="btn1">add</button></div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="btn btn-info" id="btn2" type="submit" value="submit" formaction="<?php echo base_url();?>homeController/upload">Save</button></div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {

      var x =1;
      $('#btn1').hide();
      $('body').on('keyup', '.field', function(){
        var search_text = $('.field').last().val();
          if(search_text==""){
              $('#btn1').hide();
          }else{
     $('#btn1').show();
    }
  });
      $("#btn1").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
           $('#new').append('<li" id="try-'+x+'"><input class= "box" type="checkbox"><input  name="list[]" class="set field" type="text" value=""></li>'); 
      $('#btn1').hide();
            x++;      
       });

       $('body').on('click', '.box', function(){
         var sta = 'checked';
    // i also need to pass the id of the clicked checkbox
                    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>homeController/statuspass",
        data: {search_name:sta},
        success: function(data){
         // console.log(success);

        }
                });
                  });

});
</script>
```

When I click the checkbox that checkbox id and a sting has to be passed to controller and I need to save the string on data base.

When I try, I get this error:

```
    POST http://localhost/todolist/homeController/statuspass 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ (index):146
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
y.handle @ jquery.min.js:2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got error at server side.
Try to debug your php via xDebug or to die() messages in your controller action to see what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Your Js code should by typically something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#myFormSubmit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var id = $('#hiddenInputThatHasMyID').val();
    var blah = 'blah';
    var blahblah = 'blahblah',

    // I expect you to already know how to get the above vars or you can search an learn how to retrieve them, its not the purpose of your question here.

    // You can serialize your form like this
    // var data = $('form#myForm').serialize();

    // Or create it manually like this
    var data = {id:id, blah:blah, blahblah:blahblah};

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?= site_url('controller/method') ?>",
        method: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType:'JSON',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

That will send your data to that `controller/method` and get response from it, so in your controller's method you can wait for this:

```
public function method()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $blah = $this->input->post('blah');
    $blahblah = $this->input->post('blahblah');

    // Do your magic here and return vars
    $data['ret_var1'] = 'val1';
    $data['ret_var2'] = 'val2';

    // echo your data
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Now in your ajax response you can use your vars like this:

```
var var1 = response.var1;    // val1
var var2 = response.var2;    // val2
```

I hope this is clear enough.

**Notes:**

Always use url like this `url: "<?= site_url('controller/method') ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

code igniter url is good with under score laters..
change you controller name homeController to home_controller and check the controller name start with capital later and dose note have any capital later accept your first later and same where you extend `CI_Controller` and second check that you have `statuspass` method available in you controller class homeController or not.